# Confusion about initial conditions for $t=0^+$ to a impulse response problem

Tags: linear-systems

I'm reading an example of a Linear Systems and Signal book about finding the impulse response function to a linear, time-invariant, continuous-time (LTIC) system given by this ODE:

$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+5\frac{d}{dt}+6\right)y(t) =\left(\frac{d}{dt}+1\right) x(t)$

Where $y(t)$ is considered the output function of the system and $x(t)$ is the input function. First, we solved the homogeneous ODE to get the characteristic mode. The roots of the characteristic polynomial are $-2$ and $-3$ and, since there are fewer derivatives on the RHS than on the LHS, the impulse response function $h(t)$ is given by

$h(t) = \left(c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2 e^{-3t}\right)u(t)$

Where $u(t)$ is the unit step function, since $h(t<0) = 0$. Our job now is to determine the values of the coefficients. So the book proposes making $y(t) \Rightarrow h(t)$ and $x(t) \Rightarrow \delta(t)$ (the $\delta$ being the unit impulse that happens at $t=0$) in the ODE, which yields

$\ddot{h}(t)+5\dot{h}(t)+6h(t) =\dot{\delta}(t)+\delta(t) $

Now it comes the part I don't understand. The author reminds us that $h(0^{-}) =0$ and $\dot{h}(0^{-}) =0$ (the initial conditions just before the impulse are zero) but that at $t = 0^+$ they jump to some value because of the impulse, so let's define $h(0^{+}) =k_1$ and $\dot{h}(0^{+}) =k_2$. Now quoting the book:

> These jump discontinuities in $h(t)$ and $\dot{h}(t)$ at $t = 0$ result in impulse terms $\dot{h} (0) = k_1 \delta(t)$ and $\ddot{h}(0) = k_1 \dot{\delta}(t) + k_2 \delta(t)$ on the left-hand side.

I really don't get his reasoning! I think that maybe it's all about the unit step function defined by using the $\delta$ function as $u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \delta(\tau)d\tau$, but I'm really lost here, the author just affirms this without further explanations.

Can anyone give me a light?

Comment: By "EDO" do you mean "ODE"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking in Portuguese. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The first identity, $\dot{h}(0)=k_1\delta(t)$, is based on the fact that the following statement must be true:

$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\dot{h}(t)dt=h(\epsilon)-h(-\epsilon)$$

This is basically the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (I say "basically" because it's probably due to a more general version of the theorem that includes distributions rather than just functions). Substituting, we have that $h(\epsilon)=k_1$ and $h(-\epsilon)=0$, so:

$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \dot{h}(t)dt=k_1$$

The key is that this is true *no matter how small* $\epsilon$ *is*. Now let's look at the definition of the Dirac delta function: it's the distribution $\delta(t)$ such that $\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta(t)dt=1$, no matter how small $\epsilon$ is. If we compare this definition with the above result, we must have that $\dot{h}(t)=k_1\delta(t)$ for values infinitesimally close to zero. I wouldn't personally write this as $\dot{h}(0)=k_1\delta(t)$, but this is what the author means by that statement.

For $\ddot{h}$, the basic idea is the same, though the manipulation is more difficult.

Comment: OK, really liked your explanation, but could you give some ideia of how $k_1 \dot{\delta}(t)$ appears for $\ddot{h}$?